# how to call web api inside of azure sql cloud? is it supported?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

my question is simple but i can not find an answer . calling restful service in sql stored procedure . i decided to deploy my azure environment. but my team lead said "it is not supported" could you show me how to implement in hosted azure sql? can i call it from AZURE environment in azure SP?

### Query

```
select Name
      ,xml_data.value('(/data/info/@x)[1]', 'int') as [Info.x]
      ,xml_data.value('(/data/info/@y)[1]', 'int') as [Info.y]
      ,xml_data.value('(/data/info/.)[1]', 'varchar(10)') as [Info]
from   #temp
```

### Result

```
Name     Info.x    Info.y    Info
-------  --------  --------  ---------
one         42        99     Red
two         27        72     Blue
three       16        51     Green
four        12        37     Yellow
```

.
------ Edit [2014-01-29] ------

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure's SQL Database *service* does not support CLR-based stored procedures. Assuming this is how you were making REST calls, you wouldn't be able to do it from SQL Database service. Rather, you'd need to work with SQL Server itself (which requires Virtual Machines for installation, whether standalone, mirrored, or AlwaysOn). SQL Server, running in Azure Virtual Machines, is a tested / supported workload configuration.

More information about the differences between SQL Server and Azure SQL Database service can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394115.aspx).